# What does 'for' mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

At first, I understood the boldfaced **for all** as *in spite of*, but now I've found **of** after that, which made me confused. What does the last sentence mean?

> The journey to discovering your authentic self promises to be the most
>   rewarding adventure of your life. When you know yourself, you are
>   free. You have a power and presence that radiates from deep within and
>   shines out confidently into the world. You did not come into this life
>   to suffer, to be manipulated and denied. Whatever binds you and keeps
>   you from living your truth is false and can be shed. It takes courage
>   to embrace your authentic self and live life on your own terms. Yet to
>   be uniquely you, to listen within and love yourself **for all** of
>   your weaknesses and missteps, is what your soul longs for.
>
> > [Discover Your Authentic Self: Be You, Be Free, Be Happy
> >     By Sherrie Dillard](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=XyAcDAAAQBAJ&pg=PP13&lpg=PP13&dq=The+journey+to+discovering+your+authentic+self+promises+to+be+the+most+rewarding+adventure+of+your+life.&source=bl&ots=TW2t7yzNy5&sig=Gipqi7WaMKgLQ-m1oUh8rJcuXGU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHm6mPwOLeAhVGurwKHXeOB2AQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20journey%20to%20discovering%20your%20authentic%20self%20promises%20to%20be%20the%20most%20rewarding%20adventure%20of%20your%20life.&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, "for all (of) your weakness" means in spite of every bit of weakness you have.

> all your weakness
>
> all of your weakness

are slightly different ways of expressing the idea.

> He ate all the cake.
>
> He ate all of the cake.

The cake is gone in either case.  The second, with **of**, presents the cake as something from which some or a piece can be taken.

**all** in the first expresses the idea "the *entire* thing".

**all** in the second expresses the idea "every *bit* of it".